# SQL Server 2008 R2: Update table values which matched with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**Table**: `l_test1`

```
CREATE TABLE l_test1
(
    Cola VARCHAR(10)
);
```

**Table**: `l_test2`

```
CREATE TABLE l_test2
(
    Cola VARCHAR(20)
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
INSERT INTO l_test1 VALUES('1');
INSERT INTO l_test1 VALUES('12');
INSERT INTO l_test1 VALUES('123');
INSERT INTO l_test1 VALUES('1234');

INSERT INTO l_test2 VALUES('991234567890');
INSERT INTO l_test2 VALUES('9912345678901');
INSERT INTO l_test2 VALUES('99123456789012');
INSERT INTO l_test2 VALUES('123991234567890');
INSERT INTO l_test2 VALUES('981234567890');
INSERT INTO l_test2 VALUES('1234991234567890');
INSERT INTO l_test2 VALUES('1981234567890');
```

**Note**: Now I want to remove the starting and ending numbers of table `l_test2` which are matched with the numbers 
present in the table `l_test1`.

For example: In the above table I have `1,12,123,1234` values in the table `l_test1`. Now I want 
to remove the values of table `l_test2` which are matched with these numbers. The second record in the 
table `l_test2` match the value `1` in the table `l_test1` so it should be remove.

After updating all the values the table `l_test2` should looks like:

**Expected Result**:

```
Cola
---------------------------
991234567890
991234567890
991234567890
991234567890
981234567890
991234567890
981234567890
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `STUFF`:

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372926)**

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
    SELECT t2.Cola, MAX(t1.Cola) AS r
    FROM #l_test2 t2
    JOIN #l_test1 t1
      ON t2.Cola LIKE t1.Cola + '%'
    GROUP BY t2.Cola
),
cte2 AS
(
    SELECT t2.Cola, MAX(t1.Cola) AS r
    FROM #l_test2 t2
    JOIN #l_test1 t1
     ON t2.Cola LIKE '%' + t1.Cola 
    GROUP BY t2.Cola
), cte3 AS
(
    SELECT Cola, STUFF(Cola, 1, LEN(r), '') AS sanitized
    FROM cte1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Cola, STUFF(Cola, LEN(Cola) - LEN(r) + 1, LEN(r), '') AS sanitized
    FROM cte2
)
SELECT sanitized
FROM cte3
UNION ALL
SELECT Cola
FROM #l_test2 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte3 c3 WHERE c3.Cola = t.Cola);
```

I break this into parts for readability:

1. cte1 - remove prefixes
2. cte2 - remove suffixes
3. cte3 - combine sanitized
4. final - get rows that weren't sanitized

Feel free to combine my solution into more concise manner ;)

Comment: ;) Thank you so much. You'r awesome as usual :)

Comment: The result is not as expected in rows 4 and 5. The data ends with 1 and 2 and not 0.

Comment: @Uporabnik003, Oh! yeah! Just now I came to know.

Comment: @MAK Updated my solution

Comment: @Uporabnik003, Thank you for finding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an easy way of doing this.  Here is a method which tries removing all combinations and then looks for the shortest resulting value:

```
select substring(cola,
                 len(t1b.cola),
                 len(cola) - ( len(t1b.cola) + len(t1e.cola) )
                ) as new_cola
from (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by seqnum order by len(t1b.cola) + len(t1e.cola) desc) as seqnum
      from (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
            from l_test2 t2
           ) t2 left join
           l_test1 t1b
           on t2.cola like t1b.cola + '%' left join
           l_test1 t1e
           on t2.cola like '%' + t1e.cola
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query that employs [**`PATINDEX`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       Cola, 
       SUBSTRING(Cola, left_index + 1, right_index - left_index - 1) AS sanitized_Cola
FROM (
   SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN t3.left_match = 1 THEN LEN(t1.Cola) ELSE 0 END) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY t2.Cola) AS left_index,
          MIN(CASE WHEN right_match = 0 THEN LEN(t2.Cola)+1 ELSE right_match END) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY t2.Cola) AS right_index,                       
          t2.Cola
   FROM l_test2 AS t2
   CROSS JOIN l_test1 AS t1
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX(t1.Cola + '%', t2.Cola) AS left_match) AS t3 
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%' + t1.Cola, t2.Cola) AS right_match) AS t4 ) AS q
```

The idea is to find the *biggest matching pattern* (if any) left-wise as well as right-wise. Then use the indexes of those matches in `SUBSTRING` to get the sanitized string.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dfb61/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT L2.Cola, max(L1.Cola) AS substr ,'pre' as Flag
    FROM l_test1 L1 INNER JOIN l_test2 L2 ON L2.Cola LIKE L1.Cola+'%'
group by L2.Cola
union all 
SELECT L2.Cola, max(L1.Cola) AS substr ,'post' as Flag
    FROM l_test1 L1 INNER JOIN l_test2 L2 ON L2.Cola LIKE '%'+L1.Cola
group by L2.Cola
)
update l2   
    set Cola = SUBSTRING(cte.Cola,case Flag when 'pre' then len(substr) + 1 else 1 end,
                                len(cte.cola) - len(substr))
    from l_test2 l2 inner join cte on l2.Cola = cte.Cola;
```

One CTE to get the max matched string and the len of this matched string.